# how do I tell which UITextField just triggered the textFieldShouldReturn callback?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have mulitple UITextFields in a view.

I'm assuming the place to capture the vlue of a UITextField once the user comes out of it is to implement the delegate method "textFieldShouldReturn".

Question - In "`textFieldShouldReturn`" however, how do I tell which of the UITextField's triggered this?

For example assuming at this stage I now need to update my data model with the value of what the UITextField now shows, so need to update the correct field in the model with aligns with that particular UITextField.

PS If there's a better approach, or a way to kind of "binding" approach I'm missing I'd be interested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...or you can skip all the tags and make your UITextViews instance vars and do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    myTextView1 = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    myTextView2 = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    myTextView3 = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    myTextView4 = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    ......
}

- (void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    BOOL shouldReturn = NO;

    if (textField == myTextView1)
    {
        shouldReturn = YES;
    }

    ...and so on...

    }

... release the instance vars in the dealloc...
```

I kinda prefer this way, but the other answer will work too.

Comment: This is how it was meant to be done. The "accepted" answer is way too complicated.

Comment: Just to chime in with my two cents... I think the extra iVar memory usage is minimal since we're just holding a few bytes of pointers and not really duplicating the UITextField objects. If it were the objects themselves I might code it differently.

Comment: Releasing the text fields does not necessarily deallocate them. As  matter of fact, they are retained when you add them to the view, and they are not deallocated. If they had been deallocated, the textFieldShouldReturn method would never be called with a reference to a deallocated text field. What Richard recommends is having some pointers "hanging around" as properties. That's a lot different from having whole object instances in memory, which you are going to have anyway.